# Two applications of limit theorems - which one is wrong?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n,\ldots$ be IID random variables, each one of the exponential distribution, with the mean 1.
In order to calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i \leq 1)$, we may use CLT, and obtain: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-1) \leq 0) =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i-1 }{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} \leq 0) = P(Z \leq 0)=\frac{1}{2},$$
where $Z$ is normally distributed. However I see another solution. By the law of large numbers, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i = 1$ in probability and therefore also in distribution. Therefore $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \leq 1) = F_{\delta_1} (1) = 1_{[1,\infty)} (1) = 1$, where $F_{\delta_1}$ is the distribution function of the distribution concentrated at 1.

Could you please help me and explain, which solution is wrong and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convergence in distribution means that the cdfs. converge to the limiting cdf. at continuity points of the limiting cdf.

The point $1$ is not a continuity point of $1_{[1,\infty)}$.

It does imply that, for any $\delta>0$, 
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \leq 1-\delta) = 0 $
and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \leq 1+\delta) = 1 $, so the results are consistent. It says nothing about
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \leq 1)$.